# Vertical stacking of plots in two-by-two order with Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to have vertical stacked plots in two-by-two order. I wrote a code and it gives me two horizontal graphs but I do not know how to stack next 2 graphs below them.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
print(df.columns)


for feature in df.columns:

     data = df[feature].tolist()
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

     sns.distplot(data, bins = 25, ax = ax[0], norm_hist = False, hist = True, kde=False).set_title(feature)
     sns.distplot(data, bins = 25, ax = ax[1], norm_hist = True, hist = True, kde=True).set_title(feature)

     plt.show()
```

Comment: removing subplot will help

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the `subplot`  and use `plt.show` at end

this will stack them one above the other

Answer (score 0):

You should only setup the figure once.

Give it as many columns as your data has features.
Next you fill it with your features

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(df.columns),2)

for i, feature in enumerate(df.columns):

     data = df[feature].tolist()

     sns.distplot(data, bins = 25, ax = ax[i,0], norm_hist = False, hist = True, kde=False).set_title(feature)
     sns.distplot(data, bins = 25, ax = ax[i,1], norm_hist = True, hist = True, kde=True).set_title(feature)

 plt.show()
```